# Как в AndroidStudio обработать нажатие кнопки на Bluetooth-гарнитуре?

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk

Пишу приложение для Andoroid 12, использую Kotlin. Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии кнопки на блютуз-гарнитуре, подключенной к смартфону, в приложении вызывалась функция. Не совсем понимаю, как это сделать. Можете, пожалуйста, помочь разобраться?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.